# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions - Lost Here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

painful week, I'm not sure why I get this: `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions`.

Refers to this:

```
const login = await container.props().login(email, password)
      login()
```

Note that **this worked originally** before I changed everything to async since I had to throw superagent into the mix:

```
const login = container.props().login(email, password)
          login()
```

Other combinations I've tried with no luck:

```
const login = await container.dive().find(Login).props().login(email, password)
          login()

const login = await container.dive().props().login(email, password)
          login()

const login = container.props().login(email, password)
          login()
```

Now the code:

**Test**

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

import { React, shallow, expect, nock } from '../testImports'
import LoginContainer, { Login } from '../../../client/containers/LoginContainer'
import initStore from '../../../client/store'

describe('Feature: User Authentication', () => {
  describe('Scenario: User can Login', () => {
    let email, password, store, responseBody

    beforeEach(() => {
      email = 'someuser@gmail.com'
      password = 'password'
      responseBody = { session: '05833a20-4035', token: 'pXVCJ9.eyJpYXQ' }
      store = initStore({
        user: {
          requesting: false,
          token: null,
          session: null
        }})
    })


    it('user can request authentication', async () => {
          const test = store.getState()
          const container = shallow(<LoginContainer store={store} />)
          const login = await container.props().login(email, password)

          login()
          const state = store.getState()

          expect(state.user.requesting).to.be.true
        })
})
```

**LoginContainer**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import * as AsyncActions from '../actions/User/UserAsyncActions'
import Login from '../components/Login/Login'

class LoginContainer extends Component {

  render(){
    return( <Login login={this.props.login} /> )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    requesting: state.user.requesting,
    token: state.user.token,
    session: state.user.session
  }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  login: AsyncActions.login
}

export { Login }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer)
```

**UserActions**

```
import ActionsTypes from '../ActionTypes'

export function requestLogin() {
  return ActionsTypes.USER_REQUESTED_LOGIN
}

export function loginResponded(token, session) {
  return {
    type: ActionsTypes.USER_LOGIN_RESPONDED,
    token: token,
    session: session
  }
}
```

**UserAsyncActions**

```
import UserApi from '../../../client/Api/UserApi'
import * as UserActions from './UserActions'

export async function login(email, password) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(UserActions.requestLogin())
    const response = await UserApi.loginUser(email, password),
      token = response.body.token,
      session = response.body.session
    dispatch(UserActions.loginResponded(token, session))
  }
}

export default login
```

**initStore**

```
export default (initialState = {}) => {
  let middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)

  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, middleware)

  return store
}
```

Note that this is how I'm creating the store instance in my test:

```
store = initStore({
      user: {
        requesting: false,
        token: null,
        session: null
      }}),
```

Comment: What does `UserActions.requestLogin()` return?

Comment: Updated it, see above now

Comment: I feel like it's treating this as a syncronous non-thunk action in LoginContainer.  Something about when I try to call login through props() it does't view it as a thunk action: export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  login: AsyncActions.login
}.  So when I call container.props().login(), I verified that login is a prop for sure and that it's a function for sure but it's just not treating it the same as if I were to test that AsyncAction creator straight up without going through the container props

Answer (score 0):

The call of `dispatch(UserActions.requestLogin())` turns out to be `dispatch(ActionsTypes.USER_REQUESTED_LOGIN)`

I suppose `USER_REQUESTED_LOGIN` is a string since it's an action type, that's why it complains. Your `requestLogin()` action creator should return an object, for example `{ type: ActionsTypes.USER_REQUESTED_LOGIN }`

Another potential cause may come from

```
export async function login(email, password) { ...
```

`async` function implicitly wraps returned value in a promise, so what `login(email, password)` returns is a promise with the thunk wrapped inside, as a result, the thunk middleware won't be able to handle it.

Comment: the problem isn't with that one.  That one has been like that for a while now.  The problem is elsewhere.  I've always been able to hit that in my action creator just fine like it is

Comment: the problems are more likely with my async implementation

Comment: it's pointing to this line being the problem and I think it stems from what kind of object is being turned from the mapDispatchToProps property: container.props().login(email, password)

Comment: ah I think your second thing might be right.  I tried removing async but it broke a bunch of my other tests but let me try to remove that and get all the tests to work again. I'm doing something wrong somewhere else plus that I bet